# Debounce Redux Thunk action creator function

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-redux, redux-thunk, debouncing

In my React.js project, I have a form and on input change I am calling an action creator function `updateTravellerForm`. I am using lodash's debounce method. Also, I am using redux-thunk middleware.

Earlier I tried `export const updateTravellerForm = debounce({ tvlr: newTvlr, contactDetails }) => { ... }, 500)`

But this didn't work, I was getting errors. Don't know why. I'd appreciate explanation for this case.

then I did this:

```
export const updateTravellerForm = ({ tvlr: newTvlr, contactDetails }) => {

  return debounce((dispatch, getState) => {

    if (!isEmpty(newTvlr?.traveller?.travellerClientId)) {

      const { travellerClientId } = newTvlr.traveller;

      const { travellerForm } = getState().SimplifiedReviewTraveller;
      const { associatedTravellers } = travellerForm || {};

      const updatedAssocTravellers = associatedTravellers.map((tvlr) => {
        if ( tvlr.traveller.travellerClientId === travellerClientId ) {
          return newTvlr;
        }

        return tvlr;
      });

      dispatch({
        type: actionType.UPDATE_NEW_TRAVELLERS_LIST,
        payload: updatedAssocTravellers,
      });
    }


    if(!isEmpty(contactDetails?.rowFields)) {
      dispatch({
        type: actionType.UPDATE_TRAVELLER_CONTACT_INFO,
        payload: contactDetails.rowFields,
      });
    }

  }, 300)
};
```

this seems to be working but I am not sure if this is the right way to do this.
Please let me know if the above code is fine or not and also what should be the ideal time in milliseconds to debounce?

Thanks

Comment: There is a syntax error in the code you tired before